# Rebuilt RAID6 Array Mounting Issue

Tags: data-recovery, raid, nas

Having succssfully imaged the 7 hard disk drives from a failed Thecus N7700 Pro NAS and having apparently successfully rebuilt the RAID6 array from backed images I'm getting an old PV header warning error whn attempting to mount the RAID6 array as well as an error when attempting to update the volum group metadata.

Below are the steps taken following from rebuilding the array for reference. Any guidance/advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The commands used to add the 7 hard disk drive images to the loop devices was as follows:

```
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop0
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop1
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop2
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop3
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop4
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop5
$ sudo losetup -fPr --show /media/<target drive mount point>/recovery/hdd<id>.img
Returned output:
/dev/loop6
```

**Rebuild RAID6 Array**

Add each of the RAID6 array drive images to the next available loop device using the following command:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
Returned output:
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 7 drives.
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 7 drives.
```

**Check Block Devices**

Check all block devices using the following command:

```
$ sudo lsblk                       
Returned output:
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0             7:0    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop0p1       259:0    0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop0p2       259:1    0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
loop1             7:1    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop1p1       259:2    0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop1p2       259:3    0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
loop2             7:2    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop2p1       259:4    0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop2p2       259:5    0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
loop3             7:3    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop3p1       259:6    0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop3p2       259:7    0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
loop4             7:4    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop4p1       259:8    0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop4p2       259:9    0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
loop5             7:5    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop5p1       259:10   0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop5p2       259:11   0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
loop6             7:6    0   1.8T  1 loop  
├─loop6p1       259:12   0   1.9G  1 part  
│ └─md0           9:0    0   1.9G  1 raid1 
└─loop6p2       259:13   0   1.8T  1 part  
  └─md1           9:1    0   9.1T  1 raid6 
    ├─vg0-syslv 254:0    0     1G  0 lvm   
    └─vg0-lv0   254:1    0   8.6T  0 lvm   
sda               8:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0  23.3G  0 part  /
├─sda3            8:3    0   9.3G  0 part  /var
├─sda4            8:4    0   977M  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sda5            8:5    0   1.9G  0 part  /tmp
└─sda6            8:6    0   918G  0 part  /home
sdb               8:16   0  10.9T  0 disk  
└─sdb1            8:17   0  10.9T  0 part  /media/<user>/7DFF-F49D
sdc               8:32   0  16.4T  0 disk  
└─sdc1            8:33   0  16.4T  0 part  /media/<user>/data
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

**Check Rebuilt RAID6 Array Details**

Check rebuilt RAID6 array details using the following command:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md1                
Returned output:
/dev/md1:
           Version : 0.90
     Creation Time : Tue Apr 27 16:44:08 2010
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 9757760000 (9.09 TiB 9.99 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 1951552000 (1861.15 GiB 1998.39 GB)
      Raid Devices : 7
     Total Devices : 7
   Preferred Minor : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Mar 26 02:00:20 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 7
   Working Devices : 7
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

              UUID : ea8bd249:df05f100:4d76e077:2dd3364e
            Events : 0.23046

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        1        0      active sync   /dev/loop0p2
       1     259        3        1      active sync   /dev/loop1p2
       2     259        5        2      active sync   /dev/loop2p2
       3     259        7        3      active sync   /dev/loop3p2
       4     259        9        4      active sync   /dev/loop4p2
       5     259       11        5      active sync   /dev/loop5p2
       6     259       13        6      active sync   /dev/loop6p2
```

Create & Check Mdadm Configuration File

Note: Root permissions required to run this task.
Create a mdadm.conf file using the following command:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Check the created mdadm.conf file using the following command:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/mdadm.conf                    
Returned output:
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.0 name=RCLSVR01:0 UUID=a87e6315:d3fe49fe:3a2d39f8:7977760a
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=ea8bd249:df05f100:4d76e077:2dd3364e
```

**Mount Rebuilt RAID6 Array Attempts**

Create data recovery mountpoint using the following command:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/RCLSVR
```

Try to mount the RAID6 array using the following command:

```
$ sudo mount -r /dev/md1 /mnt/RCLSVR
Returned output:
mount: /mnt/RCLSVR: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Check the logical volume groups using the following command:

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
Returned output:
  WARNING: PV /dev/md1 in VG vg0 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/syslv
  LV Name                syslv
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                e5ZreA-S8TO-2x0x-4pfw-Zh6h-Cs5X-EH8FVc
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  [#] open                 0
  LV Size                1.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     16384
  Block device           254:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/lv0
  LV Name                lv0
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                bkVNXL-2FI6-61z7-4UzW-Erwu-0sHA-oiHxbq
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  [#] open                 0
  LV Size                8.63 TiB
  Current LE             4525773
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     16384
  Block device           254:1
```

Try to mount the RAID6 array using the following command:

```
$ sudo mount -r /dev/vg0/lv0 /mnt/RCLSVR
Returned output:
mount: /mnt/RCLSVR: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-lv0.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Try to locate the superblock information for the RAID6 array using the following commands:

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/vg0/lv0 | grep superblock                                                                
Returned output:
dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/vg0/lv0
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/vg0/syslv | grep superblock                                                                 
Returned output:
dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-1
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32769
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98305
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163841
  Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229377
```

Try to mount the RAID6 array using the following command:

```
$ sudo mount -r /dev/vg0/syslv /mnt/RCLSVR
Returned output:
mount: /mnt/RCLSVR: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-syslv.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Check the active status of the RAID6 array volume groups using the following command:

```
$ sudo lvscan
Returned output:
WARNING: PV /dev/md1 in VG vg0 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/syslv' [1.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/lv0' [8.63 TiB] inherit
```

Try to mount the RAID6 array using the following command:

```
$ sudo mount -o ro /dev/vg0/syslv /mnt/RCLSVR
Returned output:
mount: /mnt/RCLSVR: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-syslv.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Try to update volume group metadata for the RAID6 array using the following command:

```
$ sudo vgck --updatemetadata vg0
Returned output:
  WARNING: PV /dev/md1 in VG vg0 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  WARNING: updating PV header on /dev/md1 for VG vg0.
  Error writing device /dev/md1 at 4096 length 512.
  WARNING: bcache_invalidate: block (7, 0) still dirty.
  Failed to write mda header to /dev/md1.
  Failed to write VG.
```

Comment: which filesystem on those LVs? (check with `file -s`) Since it's read-only, you might have more luck with `mount -o loop,ro` options, some filesystems also need an extra noload / norecovery / or similar options. if the filesystem must write to recover, you can use [a copy-on-write overlay](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file)

Comment: also check dmesg after mount failure as it might have some more info

Comment: @frostshutz - Thank you kindly for reply. Below is the information requested:
$ sudo file -s /dev/vg0/syslv
/dev/vg0/syslv: symbolic link to ../dm-0
$ sudo file -s /dev/vg0/lv0
/dev/vg0/lv0: symbolic link to ../dm-1
$ sudo file -s /dev/dm-0
/dev/dm-0: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=a1b7e21f-6687-4196-9c14-97d9a21e55b5 (needs journal recovery) (large files)
$ sudo file -s /dev/dm-1     
/dev/dm-1: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 256, v2 dirs)

Comment: @rostshutz - Once the disk images were successfully created the write permisssions were also removed from the image files to protect them. 
Below is dmesg info requested:                                         
...
[116256.308894] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[116256.309193] EXT4-fs (dm-0): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[116256.309195] EXT4-fs (dm-0): write access will be enabled during recovery
[116256.309676] Trying to write to read-only block-device md1
...
[116256.309685] Trying to write to read-only block-device md1
...

Answer (score 1):

@frostschutz - The point made about the filesystem possibly needing to be able to write to recover helped resolve the issue. Apologies for the misspelling of your username in my comments.
The steps below were taken to backtrack to the position before creating the original loop devices as well as those taken to successfully recreate the loop devices, and reassemble and mount the RAID6 array.

**Deactivate LV Group**
$ sudo vgchange -a n /dev/vg0

**Remove Mdadm Congifuration & Data**
$ sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge mdadm

**Detach Loop Devices**
$ sudo losetup -a
$ sudo losetup -D
$ sudo losetup -l
$ sudo dmsetup remove /dev/loop0 dev/loop1 dev/loop2 dev/loop3 dev/loop4 dev/loop5 dev/loop6
Reboot the computer.
Login and check loop devices again to make sure they are gone.
$ sudo losetup -a

**Change Disk Image File Permissions**
$ sudo chmod +w /media//recovery/*.img

**Add Images in Writable Mode**
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop0
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop1
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop2
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop3
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop4
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop5
$ sudo losetup -fP --show /media/[target drive mount point]/recovery/hdd[id].img
Returned output:
/dev/loop6

**Reinstall mdadm**
$ sudo apt-get install mdadm

**Rebuild RAID6 Array**
Add each of the RAID6 array drive images to the next available loop device using the following command:
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
Returned output:
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 7 drives.
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 7 drives.

**Check Logical Volumes Status**
$ sudo lvscan
Returned output:
WARNING: PV /dev/md1 in VG vg0 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/syslv' [1.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/lv0' [8.63 TiB] inherit

**Display Logical Volumes Details**
$ sudo lvdisplay
Returned output:
WARNING: PV /dev/md1 in VG vg0 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg0/syslv
LV Name                syslv
VG Name                vg0
LV UUID                e5ZreA-S8TO-2x0x-4pfw-Zh6h-Cs5X-EH8FVc
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time , 
LV Status              available
[#] open                 0
LV Size                1.00 GiB
Current LE             512
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     16384
Block device           254:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg0/lv0
LV Name                lv0
VG Name                vg0
LV UUID                bkVNXL-2FI6-61z7-4UzW-Erwu-0sHA-oiHxbq
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time , 
LV Status              available
[#] open                 0
LV Size                8.63 TiB
Current LE             4525773
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     16384
Block device           254:1

**Update Volume Group Metadata**
$ sudo vgck --updatemetadata vg0
Returned output:
WARNING: PV /dev/md1 in VG vg0 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
WARNING: updating PV header on /dev/md1 for VG vg0.

**Mount Recovered RAID6 Array**
$ sudo mount -o ro /dev/vg0/lv0 /mnt/RCLSVR

At that point it was then possible to access and recover the data.
Hope this helps others and many thanks again for your assistance @frostschutz.